# Limit 4000 concurrent users with haproxy socket.io

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io, haproxy

I’m trying to connect 100.000 concurrent users to my application but when I connect more than 4000 users all websockets are disconnected.

Architecture of the app is a monolithic architecture with HAProxy, API application, the websockets system are 10 node applications running, MySql and Redis.

I have implemented several solutions but something is not working:

- https://www.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/
- http://x-team.com/2016/02/socket-io-haproxy-aws/

I have updated hard and soft nofile limit to 1M and possible opened file hadles and the size of the NAT ip connection tracking table.

**Clients**

I have another instance with a client. For testing porpouses I run one client with 1K users and all users are connected. I repeat the process in a new shell. With 4000 clients all works but if I run another client with 1K or 100 users all users are disconnected and begin reconnections in a loop.

Where is the problem?

**CONFIGURATION**

**Server**

AWS EC2 m3.xlarge instance 4 cores and 15GB Ram.

**Server stack**

HA-Proxy version 1.5.8
Socket.io 1.3.7
Debian 8

Haproxy config file haproxy.cfg

```
global
log /dev/log    local0
log /dev/log    local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
stats timeout 30s
user haproxy
group haproxy
maxconn  100000
daemon

# Default SSL material locations
ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
crt-base /etc/ssl/private

# Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
# For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
#  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/

ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3


defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    maxconn  100000
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


frontend http-in
  bind *:80


    # Define hosts
  acl is_api_domain hdr(host) -i api.xxxx.com
  acl is_rtp_domain hdr(host) -i rtp.xxxx.com

  # Backends
  use_backend server_api if is_api_domain
  use_backend server_rtp if is_rtp_domain

  default_backend server_api

backend server_api
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  option tcplog

  server  apiApp 127.0.0.1:3002

backend server_rtp
  balance   roundrobin
  server  rtpApp0 127.0.0.1:8500
  server  rtpApp1 127.0.0.1:8501
  server  rtpApp2 127.0.0.1:8502
  server  rtpApp3 127.0.0.1:8503
  server  rtpApp4 127.0.0.1:8504
  server  rtpApp5 127.0.0.1:8505
  server  rtpApp6 127.0.0.1:8506
  server  rtpApp7 127.0.0.1:8507
  server  rtpApp8 127.0.0.1:8508
  server  rtpApp9 127.0.0.1:8509
```

$ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 60221
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1000000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 60221
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
fs.file-max = 1000000
fs.nr_open = 1000000    
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1048576
net.nf_conntrack_max = 1048576
```

Comment: HAProxy 1.5.8 was released over a year ago and has seen numerous bugfixes released since then. I would suggest that you definitely should not be trying to troubleshoot with that version.  Verify your version, please?  Current in 1.5.x is 1.5.18.

Comment: Assuming that you are actually running 1.5.18 and 1.5.8 was a typographical error, the logs from HAProxy from a few of the dropped connections may provide useful troubleshooting info to pinpoint the direction where the trouble originated -- client, server, or internally.

Comment: I use Debian 8 and default version of HAProxy is 1.5.8. I think that version of HAProxy is not the problem because I tried Apache 2.4 before and I had the same issue.

Comment: Logs from HAProxy don't give revelant information. The first line when websocket is connected:

`Nov  4 12:27:36 ip-10-43-223-196 haproxy[381]: 54.221.94.137:16139 [04/Nov/2016:12:27:10.567] http-in server_rtp/rtpApp7 0/0/0/5/25937 101 376 - - ---- 12/12/12/10/0 0/0 "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1"`

Comment: I agree, if this is a session that unexpectedly ended, then the HAProxy log doesn't explain where the trouble is, but it does tend to prove your theory that the problem is not HAProxy.  The [session state at disconnect](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#8.5) flags, shown here as `----` suggests that no error occurred inside HAProxy and that this connection terminated normally -- not lost, not killed, and not a case where one side disappeared unexpectedly.

Comment: So, it seems you need to focus on the code in Node. What does it log when this happens?

Comment: I have tried with 1 application and with 10 application running in 10 several ports. Both cases connections up to 4.000 users works fine. If issue is in the code then running 10 applications the limit should be 40.000 and not 4.000. Logs of the application haven't exception or another similar errors.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are right. I have built a little application only with websockets and the limit is more than 250K concurrent users. I'll focus on the code. Thanks!

Comment: In my app I use Redis and Redis has a default limit to 4096 for maxclients. I set to 65355 and it's working. Source: https://github.com/lamby/pkg-redis/issues/8

Comment: Good work finding the underlying problem.  Please post the solution as an answer, for the benefit of future visitors... but consider also whether this is the ideal solution... does each client really need a persistent Redis connection? Is that efficient and will it scale?

Comment: @eltortuganegra I have a very similar setup for an personal application I've been working on. Are you using socket.io and I was wondering if you had any quick guidelines on sticky connections for the sockets even though you have 10 node servers running?